# Google Calendar list events method not returning any events

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

The [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list) is not returning all the events.

I see a lot of events on the calendar, but when I call [Events: list](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events/list), I get only some of them.

It's not a matter of maxResults being too low. I have it set to return 2500, the max. I get 1251 or so, I deleted about 24 via the API, and now it returns 1227.  However there are a bunch on the calendar that aren't coming back.

It's not a matter of the page token either. I'm looping to see if somehow the rest are on the next pageToken list, but when I call getNextPageToken after the first page, it's null.

The optional parameters I'm using is:

```
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 2500,
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'pageToken' => $pageToken,
    );
```

If I set singleEvents to be false, or remove it, Google responds with an error.

> **singleEvents**  boolean Whether to expand recurring events into instances
>   and only return single one-off events and instances of recurring
>   events, but not the underlying recurring events themselves. Optional.
>   The default is False.

This seemed to start happening about when Google changed the GMail name to [G suites](https://gsuite.google.com/together/).

My code is below: (when I var_dump $calendarList, I get only 1 calendar.  I used similar code to add the calendar events in the first place.)

```
$calendarList  = $service->calendarList->listCalendarList();
$calendarListEntry = $service->calendarList->get('primary');

$continue = 1;
echo "reading the calendar for duplicate appointments<br>";
while ($continue == 1) {
    $optParams = array(
        'maxResults' => 2500,
        'singleEvents' => TRUE,
        'pageToken' => $pageToken,
    );

    $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id, $optParams);
    foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
        //process events
    }
    $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
    if ($pageToken == null) { continue = 0; }
}
```

Edit:  weirdly, when I lowered the maxResults to 250, I got a few that hadn't shown up in the result originally.  But I'm still not getting all of them.

Edit2: forgot to include the call to read the next page token.

Edit 3: Weirdly, although I'm passing in 'singleEvents' => TRUE, I'm also getting events that are marked to repeat.

Comment: what are you putting in as $pageToken and why? why not just do $events = $service->events->listEvents($calendarListEntry->id)  ?

Comment: Because if I just do listEvents, it will only return the first 250.  I'm putting in null initially as the pagetoken, and on subsequent calls I'm using the value I get back from $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();  I just forgot to add that to the code above.

Comment: OK and you don't want to paginate I guess.  what happends if you remove the singleevents and pagetoken lines then?

Comment: I AM paginating.  Did you not read my comment or see my edit?

Answer (score 1):

With pagination

```
$events = $service->events->listEvents('primary');

while(true) {
  foreach ($events->getItems() as $event) {
    echo $event->getSummary();
  }
  $pageToken = $events->getNextPageToken();
  if ($pageToken) {
    $optParams = array('pageToken' => $pageToken);
    $events = $service->events->listEvents('primary', $optParams);
  } else {
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm already paginating.  Although pagination should not matter if I have it set to 2500 and I only get 1200 back.